# How to keep leading zeros in a column when reading JSONwith Pandas?

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

```
total_list = ['123456','00123456']
df = pd.read_json(json.dumps(total_list))
print(df)
```

The result is:

```
        0
0  123456
1  123456
```

But I want to keep the '0',how can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `dtype == str`:

```
total_list = ['123456','00123456']
df = pd.read_json(json.dumps(total_list), dtype=str)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
          0
0    123456
1  00123456
```